# I'm getting Invalid Syntax with p_desc highlighted when I run this code

Tags: python, python-3.x, syntax-error

The code is supposed to add items to several dictionaries(unit_price,description,stock). But the problem is when I run the code the var name p_desc is highlighted.

I tried deleting the entire statement which resulted in p_stock being highlighted. Only when the entire elif statement is deleted does the code run.

```
while(c!= "q" or c!= "Q"):

    c= input("What would you like to do?")
    if(c=="q" or c=="Q"):
        break

    elif(c=="A" or c=="a"):

        p_no = int(input("Enter part number: "))
        p_pr = float(input("Enter part price: ")
        p_desc = input("Enter part description: ")
        p_stock = int(input("Enter part stock: "))


        for i in range(0,len(unit_price)):
            if(p_no in unit_price):
                print(p_no,"That part number already exists :(, changing value to")
                p_no+=1

        unit_price.update({p_no: p_pr})
        description.update({p_no: p_desc})
        stock.update({p_no: p_stock})
        print()
```

Comment: A lot of syntax errors going on in your code, I would suggest removing those and print the code again. For future purposes, use a Python IDE like https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/ which does syntax highlighting for you

Comment: There is only one ) in line: `p_pr = float(input("Enter part price: ")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't closed the bracket in the line above

```
  p_pr = float(input("Enter part price: ")
```

you need to close both brackets

```
  p_pr = float(input("Enter part price: "))
```

Answer (score 0):

You missed 2 closing brackets.

Change:

```
p_pr = float(input("Enter part price: ")
p_desc = input("Enter part description: ")
```

To:

```
p_pr = float(input("Enter part price: "))
p_desc = input("Enter part description: "))
```